# HTML Email - Gmail - Whitespace added between images

Tags: html-email

I'm creating an email signature template for our team. The email signature has a profile image of a team member above a table row with a dark background; however, Gmail is creating a space between bottom of the image and the section underneath. I've tried virtually everything that I could find on stackoverflow, email monks, etc.

The table's `cellspacing`, `cellpadding`, and `border` have been set to `0`. `display:block` hasn't worked, setting the `font-size` to less than `2px` hasn't either.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<tr>
  <td width="202" rowspan="3" valign="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
    <div valign="bottom">
      <img
        src="IMAGEURL.png"
        align="absbottom"
        width="202"
        height="242"
        border="0"
        style="display: block; line-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; vertical-align: bottom !important;"
      />
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't replicate unfortunately but what happens when you remove the div?
There really isn't any need for the div in there to be honest, you may as well remove it anyway and the align="bottom" should only be set on the table cell as the image will inherit that property by default. 

To be honest, it would be good if you could post your entire code you're using as it'll give us context of what you're working with. Even if it's with placeholder content like you already have done with the image path.